# Java Inheritance : Error when @Override method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have two example. First is true and second is wrong. It's just different at one point: `Animal` class and `Mammal` class.

```
public class Inheritance {

    public static class Animal {        
        public void Scream() {
            System.out.println("I'm an animal");
        }       
    }

    public  static class Mammal extends Animal{
                   //no Scream method
    }

    public  static class Tiger extends Mammal{
        public void Scream(){
            System.out.println("I'm a tiger");
        }       
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Animal tiger = new Tiger();
        tiger.Scream(); //True
    }
}
```

Second example:

```
public class Inheritance {

    public static class Animal {        
                 // no Scream method
    }

    public  static class Mammal extends Animal{
        public void Scream(){
            System.out.println("I'm a mammal");
        }       
    }

    public  static class Tiger extends Mammal{
        public void Scream(){
            System.out.println("I'm a tiger");
        }       
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Animal tiger = new Tiger();
        tiger.Scream(); //false. Error
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

@: I have edited . I have typed mismatch.

Comment: Are you asking why it is giving you an error?

Comment: It works for me, without errors... what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Both of your examples compiled and ran (and printed "I'm a tiger") fine for me. What is your problem?

Comment: What is the error? Not compiling? If so, what error does the compiler state? Runs, but gives an unexpected result? If so, what did you expect and what happens?

Comment: Are you certain?  I ran both cases and got "I'm a tiger" as the output.

Comment: I have edited my post. But now I can understand why. thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your 2 classes and they are both working.
I wouldn't work if you try something like :
Animal tiger = new Tiger();
on the second case, because Animal has not Scream() method

BTW: Usually, method names start with lower case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Both versions running perfect. 
In both cases it say "tiger"